# Passing random generated integers to an intent

Tags: android

How to take a random generated integer and pass it to another Activity?

I have worked with Intents before, however since I never see the value of the integer, I cannot specify.

Basically,

```
int w = numGen.nextInt(7);
```

How do I put `w` into the Intent and use it in another Activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("myrandom", yourRandomVal);
startActivity(this, intent);
```

In your other activity's `onCreate()`:

```
int passedRandom = getIntent().getIntExtra("myrandom");
```

The thing is you can add extras to an intent by using various `putExtra()` and then get it using `getExtra()`

Comment: the problem I guess I am having is that getIntExtra is calling for both a name and a default value. In my activity I do not know what the value is because it is randomly generated each time. When I move it to the new activity, i obviously cannot use "w" to define the value. thank you for anytime

Comment: If you always pass a value you shouldn't care about the default value. Pass 0 or anything as the default for you know you always pass a value.

Comment: so if i understand correct  intent.putExtera("myrandom", w) on this first and int passedRandom = getIntent().getIntExtra("myrandom",0) in the other activity...I am sorry I am new to all this.

Comment: That's correct. You pass a value using putExtra then get it using getExtra. getExtra wants a default value in case there's no value passed. But in your case there's always a value passed so you put 0 (or anything) as the default value. Check it, should work.

Answer (score 0):

In your class declare a const key:

```
public static final String RANDOM_INT = "random_int";
```

Add it as an extra in your Intent:

```
int someInt = 5;
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(RANDOM_INT, someInt);
startActivity(someInt);
```

In SomeActivity, get the value like so:

```
int obtainedInt = -1;
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras.containsKey(OriginalActivity.RANDOM_INT)){
    obtainedInt = extras.getInt(OriginalActivity.RANDOM_INT);    
}
```